# How to Remove Logging Output from Allure 2

Tags: spock, rest-assured, allure

I have Java/Groovy/Spock tests and Allure 2 report. I use `allure.Step()` annotation to describe all steps that I want to see in Allure report. For example:

```
def "some test"() {
  when: "do some request"
  Request.getRequest()
}

class Request {
  @Step("GET https://some.request")
  static Response getRequest() {
    return given().log().all()
            .filter(new AllureRestAssured())
            .when()
            .get(conf.url())
  }
}
```

In that case I see two basically same blocks in report:

- one beautiful block step with finely formatted request and response due to `AllureRestAssured()`
- one ugly block with the same unformatted request and response info due to `.log().all()` console output.

Is there a way to remove all console output from Allure report and leave only methods that have `@Step` annotation?

Comment: Have you tried removing `.log().all()` ?

Comment: @user16358266, That would help, but I want to see these logs in my console output when I run tests locally in IDE. I just don't want to see them in Allure report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ma college have found a solution. Separate object with all required RestAssured filters:

```
class BeforeAll {
    BeforeAll() {
        filters(new AllureRestAssured(), new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter())
    }
}
```

And call this object on test or extended Specification:

```
static BeforeAll beforeAll = new BeforeAll()
```